# Add unique elements and automatically update ObservableCollection in C#

Tags: c#, list, listview, observablecollection

I have an ObservavebleColection bound to a listView. Basically, this collection must keep up with every change in the server and receives updates in string format.

My code parses the string and adds elements to the collection, but I'm having trouble finding a way to remove elements. How can I update the collection when an element is removed or changed on the server?

Here's my code:

```
public static ObservableCollection<TransactionDetails> offerList = new ObservableCollection<TransactionDetails>();

public async static Task<ObservableCollection<TransactionDetails>> getOfferList()
    {
        // Start getting Offers

        string Offer = await BedpAPI_V1.getOfferList();

        string[] splitedResponse = Offer.Split(new[] { "@@@@" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string response in splitedResponse) {
            string[] splitedMessage = response.Split(new[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            offer.TransactionID = Convert.ToInt32(splitedMessage[0]);
            offer.Seller = splitedMessage[1];
            offer.Cost = Convert.ToDouble(splitedMessage[2]);
            offer.Duration = Convert.ToInt16(splitedMessage[3]);
            offer.Delay = Convert.ToInt16(splitedMessage[4]);
            offer.Capacity = Convert.ToDouble(splitedMessage[5]);
            offer.Availability = Convert.ToDouble(splitedMessage[6]);

            if (currentOffer <= offer.TransactionID)
            {
                offerList.Add(new TransactionDetails() { TransactionID = offer.TransactionID, Seller = offer.Seller, Cost = offer.Cost, Duration = offer.Duration, Delay = offer.Delay, Capacity = offer.Capacity, Availability = offer.Availability });

                currentOffer++;
            }
        }
        return offerList;
    }
```

Comment: @mjwills I think it's clear: "How can I update the collection when an element is removed or changed on the server?"

Comment: What does your code do now @DiogoCosta ? Does it throw an exception, for example? **What about it doesn't work?**

Comment: As it is the code does what it's supposed to (i.e. it parses the string and adds elements to the collection). I'm having trouble finding a way to remove or change current elements using the same logic I use to add them.

Comment: @mjwills I've edited the description. I hope it is more clear now.

Comment: Please show how `offerList` is declared. Would it be an option to just clear `offerList` on every call to `getOfferList` and just repopulate it from `splitedResponse`?

Comment: offerList added. I tried that, but it clears the entire collection but the last element.

Comment: `I tried that, but it clears the entire collection` Did you clear the list before or after `foreach (string response in splitedResponse) {`? _It should have been **before**._

Comment: Before. For some reason, it behaves as if I'm clearing it inside the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by clearing the collection on every call before parsing splitedResponse - as Clear() was throwing an unheld exception, had to handle it inside a throw catch block:

```
try 
{
   offerList.Clear();
}

catch (Exception ex) {

   offerList.Clear();
   Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your ListView bind with a `ObservavebleColection<>`, when you modify an element, you may fire a `OnCollectionChanged` event yourself.
Assume you modify an element using `[]`:

```
public class MyCollection : ObservableCollection<MyClass>
{
    public new MyClass this[int index]
    {
        get { return base[index]; }
        set 
        {
            base[index] = value;
            base.OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Firstly, you may want to bind your collection like:

```
myCollection = MyFunction();
MyListView.ItemsSource = myCollection;
```

If you change an item in your collection like:

```
myCollection[index] = someNewItem;
```

Then you could update your listview like:

```
MyListView.Refresh();
```

But it is recommended to use some dynamic binding.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I think that doesn't solve my problem, as my trouble is actually on how to modify an element.

Comment: I had updated the answer of a simple example using `[]` indexer.